# LWC javascript standard event body structure

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

In LWC we have this standard event which gets invoked everytime javascript function is called from html

```
<lightning-input type="text" onlick={handleOnClick} value={textValue}></lightning-input>

    handleOnClick(event) {
        this.textValue = event.target.value;
    }
```

I am little confused about the usagebility of this event the way it provides the data. Sometimes we can get the data by `event.target.value`, sometimes it provides values by using `event.customTarget.*` and sometimes it provides the value by `event.target.dataset.*`.

Also when i become unsure about how to fetch if i try to see the internal structure of event by doing the JSON.stringify(event) . It gives error saying u cannot stringify a circular object to JSON.

can anyone please explain me the usage of this event and if possible it's internal structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you use `event.target` to get values from the target element; for example, with `lightning-input`, you can access `name`, `value`, `maxLength`, `pattern`, etc. This is true even if the handler is attached to a different object, as the firing object becomes the target (e.g. an `onclick` event on a `lightning-input` sets the target to that input, even if the handler is specified elsewhere). Note that hyphenated names change from `max-length` to `maxLength`, as `-` is the math operator for subtraction.

If you attach custom data to an element, you use `event.target.dataset` to read those values. You can read more about these on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset). These are useful when you need an extra piece of data, as you can't add other undocumented attributes to a component outside of the `data-` attributes.

`event.customTarget` should never be necessary, as I've never heard of it (do you mean to say `event.currentTarget`?). You need `event.currentTarget` only if the handler is for an intermediary element from the target, and you need it for some reason. For example, you might put a div around a button, with a click handler on the div, and you need to know which div the button belongs to. This is a rare use case, but it's worth knowing that it exists.

None of this is really written in the LWC documentation, as it is expected that readers of the documentation know JavaScript and DOM material from another source, such as the [MDN Developer Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide). If you need more information on how events, or other features in JavaScript work, try out the MDN. It has all the properties and their behaviors. Events mostly follow the [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent) API, and is documented in the [LWC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch) for deviations from the standard API.

For CustomEvent events (anything a LWC developer creates with `new CustomEvent(...)`), there is a detail object that will include additional information. You access it via `event.detail.propertyName`. The documentation states which properties will be set, so check the documentation for the firing element.

For standard events, such as onClick or onBlur, the standard properties apply; check the MDN documentation for information on a specific event handler.